# Get ID of shell started using salloc

Tags: slurm

I just started using slurm and did

```
salloc -p UBUNTU bash
```

I started a script, then my system froze for another reason and I had to restart. How can I retrieve the ID of the allocated job so I can reattach and end the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the list of your jobs with:

```
squeue -u $USER
```

Assuming you connect to your cluster with SSH, if you did not start a terminal multiplexer (such as `screen` or `tmux`) your job was most probably killed as soon as your SSH session ended.